# How to specify default Lotus Notes "ACCOUNT" in mailto link

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, mailto

Searched for this issue, but couldn't find any relevant post/solution on stackoverflow. Hence asking this question.

I have a mailto link in my jsp, using which I am successfully able to launch Lotus Notes & populate Subject / To / Body / etc.

However, in Lotus Notes, I have my own user account as well as a mailin-db, and I want to send the mail using the mailin-db. But whenever I launch using mailto, it always composes using my Personal account in Lotus Notes.

Is there anything to specify "From" in the mailto link ? Also, I have already looked at various settings / options in Preferences in Lotus Notes, but couldn't find anything there either.

Request kind assistance in resolution of this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It opens the mail file set in current [location definition](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTWP_9.0.1/com.ibm.notes901.help.doc/locacc_loc_mail_settings_r.html?lang=en) on tab "Mail" always.

Open location at menu `File > Locations > Manage Locations...`.

You can change mail file to your mailin-db but I am not really sure you'll like the side effects.

Comment: Thanks a lot Knut, I could do what I needed without any trouble.. Just curious to know though, what are the side effects you are talking about here..? I didn't observe any noticeable difference in Lotus Notes functionality after changing the mail file as above...

Comment: The side effects are that you don't get alarm notifications from your personal calendar anymore, that menu "Create\Mail" is not related to your personal mail database anymore and that you don't get the "new mail" symbol in Windows task bar for your personal mails anymore.