# How to modify item value of current document in Lotus notes?

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm trying to add/update an item to a message in Lotus Notes. I've tried many approaches but couldn't get there. All I want to achieve is that when user creates a new message or edits an existing one, and clicks a button which triggers my codes, a new item will be appended to the message, or replaced if the item exists. I think the trick is through calling replaceItemValue() of Document object. The problem is that I can't find a way to access the current Document object. I know how to get NotesUIDocument and NotesBEDocument, but is not helpful. And I also tried with session.getAgentContext().getUnprocessedDocuments(). But I got null returned by session.getAgentContext().

1. What's the best practice to access current Document object to append/replace item value of a new message?
2. What's the difference and correspondence among NotesUIDocument, NotesBEDocument and Document?
3. Where is 'new message' stored? Is it stored in a Mail File?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LotusScript you'd access and change a document that's currently open with

```
Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
Set doc = uidoc.Document
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("YourItem", "YourValue")
```

`NotesUIDocument` is the document that's currently open in the Notes workspace.
`NotesDocument` is the backend document.
`NotesBEDocument` is not used.

A new message created with menu `Create / Mail / Memo` is stored in [users mail database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31726103/2065611).